# how to pass post value to upload.php form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I tried a simple post value passing to another form which are examples in the internet..All of them works but when i try to implement on my own form it does'nt work..i also tried using session..but no luck..please can someone help me..this is my first form code..the form is used for uploading multiple files using AJAX and saves the other info to mysql through upload.php where the post value should go.

index.php - upload form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php
  $cat = @$_GET['cat'];
  $subcat = @$_GET['subcat'];
  $qqq = @$_GET['qqq'];
  $con = @$_GET['con'];

  $quer2="SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"; 
  if (isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0) {
    $quer = "SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"; 
  } else {
    $quer="SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory order by subcategory"; 
  } 

  echo "<p>Category:&nbsp;";
  //File Category
  echo "<div class='dropdown'><select id='cat' name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\" class='dropdown-select'><option value=''>Click to Select</option>";
  foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2) {
    if  ($noticia2['cat_id'] == @$cat) { 
      echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[category]'>$noticia2[category]</option>"."<BR>";
    } else {
      echo  "<option value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select></div>";

  //File Sub-Category
  echo "<div class='dropdown'><select id='subcat' name='subcat' class='dropdown-select'><option value=''>Click to Select</option>";
  foreach ($dbo->query($quer) as $noticia) {
    echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcategory]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";
  }
  echo "</select></div>";
  //File Type
  echo "<div class='dropdown'><select id='qqq' name='qqq' onClick='#' class='dropdown-select'>
    <option value=''".(($qqq == '') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Click to Select</option>
    <option value='Photos'".(($qqq == 'Photos') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Photos/Images</option>
    <option value='Videos'".(($qqq == 'Videos') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Audios/Videos</option>
    <option value='PDF'".(($qqq == 'PDF') ? " selected='selected'":"").">PDF Documents</option>
    <option value='Word'".(($qqq == 'Word') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Word Documents</option>
    <option value='Presentation'".(($qqq == 'Presentation') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Power Point Presentation</option>
    <option value='Zip'".(($qqq == 'Zip') ? " selected='selected'":"").">Compressed Documents</option>";
    echo "</select></div></p>";

    $quer2="SELECT DISTINCT name,id FROM user order by name"; 
    echo "<p>Contributor:&nbsp;";
    //Contributors
    echo "<div class='dropdown' style='width:600px;'><select id='con' name='con' class='dropdown-select' style='width:600px;'><option value=''>Click to Select</option>";
    foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $contributor) {
    if ($contributor['id'] == @$con) { 
      echo "<option selected value='$contributor[name]'>$contributor[name]</option>"."<BR>";
    } else {
      echo  "<option value='$contributor[name]'>$contributor[name]</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select></div></p>";
?>
<input type="text" name="sam" id="sam" value="sample" />
<div id="mulitplefileuploader" name="photos">Choose File(s)</div>
<div id="status" ></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var settings = {
      url: "upload.php",
      method: "POST",
      allowedTypes:"jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,mp3,mp4,avi,mpeg,flv,wmv,3gp,txt,doc,docx,ppt,pdf,zip,rar",
      fileName: "myfile",
      multiple: true,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr) {
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'></font>");
      },
      onError: function(files,status,errMsg) {      
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Failed.</font>");
      }
    }
    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
  });
  </script>
</form>
```

and the upload.php where the post value should go..

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();

  include('config.php');
  //Variables
  //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
  function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
  }

  $cat = $_SESSION['cat'];
  $subcat=$_POST['sam'];


  $session_id='auto'; //$session id
  define ("MAX_SIZE","500000"); 
  function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) { return ""; }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
  }
  //If directory doesnot exists create it.
  $output_dir = "upload/";
  if (isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
    $ret = array();

    $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
 //  {  // ????

    // single file
    if (!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) {
      $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
      $size=filesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$name]);
      //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
      $ext = getExtension($filename);
      $ext = strtolower($ext);

      $uploaderid = $_SESSION['SESS_ID'];
      $uploadername = $_SESSION['SESS_PRO_PIC'];
      $uploadcat = $_POST['cat'];
      //get filename combined with time
      $image_name = time().$filename; 
      $Ficon = 'images/Dicon.png';
      $image_title = $fileName;

      echo "<img src='".$output_dir.$image_name."'>";
      $newname = $output_dir.$image_name;

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
      //Save Details
      $time = time();
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `udocs`(file_id,file_name,category,file_size,file_type,file_path,uploader_id,author,file_icon,date_upload,time_upload,image_album,section,subject) 
            VALUES ('$session_id','$image_title','$uploadcat','$size','$ext','upload/$image_title','$uploaderid','$uploadername','$Ficon','" . $_POST["fudate"] ."','" . $_POST["futime"] ."','" . $_POST["fualbum"] ."','$cat','$subcat')");
      $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
    } else {
      $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
      for ($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
        $size=filesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$name]);
        //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $ext = getExtension($filename);
        $ext = strtolower($ext);
        $ret[$fileName] = $output_dir.$fileName;

        $uploaderid = $_SESSION['SESS_ID'];
        $uploadername = $_SESSION['SESS_PRO_PIC'];
        $uploadcat ='Photos/Images';
        //get filename combined with time
        $image_name = time().$filename; 
        $Ficon = 'images/Dicon.png';
        $image_title=$filename;

        echo "<img src='".$output_dir.$image_name."'>";
        $newname = $output_dir.$image_name;

        //Sanitize the POST values

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $output_dir.$fileName );
        //Save Details
        $time = time();
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `udocs`(file_id,file_name,category,file_size,file_type,file_path,uploader_id,author,file_icon,date_upload,time_upload,image_album,section,subject) 
                VALUES ('$session_id','$image_title','$uploadcat','$size','$ext','$newname','$uploaderid','$uploadername','$Ficon','" . $_POST["fudate"] ."','" . $_POST["futime"] ."','" . $_POST["fualbum"] ."','$cat','$subcat')");

      } 
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($ret);
// } // ?? this must close the unmatched, useless opening brace above
?>
```

Comment: The *cat and *subcat should be carried to the upload.php...how should i do it?

Comment: Something totally unrelated to your question: Please look into Object Oriented Programming in PHP and also look at PHP Templating to improve maintainability of your code. Also, it will make it easy for other people to understand it to help you find solutions.

Comment: This is a duplicate about a billion times over. There are plenty of questions on how to upload files in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you understand what you do. You call `uploadFile` function right after page loaded.

Seems to me you have to load page with from, then user will select some file on his pc, then he will submit form and the you have to upload his file. So you have to call function `uploadFile` on form submit, but not like you do.

You need something like in code below.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('submit','form#formId',function() {
        var settings = {
            url: "upload.php",
            method: "POST",
            allowedTypes:"jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,mp3,mp4,avi,mpeg,flv,wmv,3gp,txt,doc,docx,ppt,pdf,zip,rar",
            fileName: "myfile",
            multiple: true,
            onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
            {
                $("#status").html("<font color='green'></font>");
            },
            onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
            {       
                $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Failed.</font>");
            }
        }
        $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
    }
});
```

In HTML you have to add `id` attribute to your form:

```
<form action="upload.php" id='formId' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

old answer deleted

Comment: In my case..where i wrote a php line inside my form..how will i alter so i can get it..because i have to query some data from my database to get lists of categories and sub categories...

Comment: So you can get what? What I suggested?

Comment: i tried what you have suggested..it works but in my case i can't solve it..i'm tired of getting what's is wrong...:(

Comment: What exactly you can't do?

Comment: I can not pass the post value in my upload.php i used $cat=$_POST['cat']; and $subcat=$_POST['subcat']; to get the post value from my index.php but when i go to my database the file category and subcategory stays null...i tried giving a constant value for $cat like $cat='engineering'; and yes it saves the value..so it means the post value from index.php are not really carried out...can you please help me...

Comment: Is it the script that is making the value null? but the session for my user id in my log in is carried...I'm not used to PHP to be honest..

Comment: @user3610167 updated my answer, but I am not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: I tried moving the script to Jquery but the result : The button choose file does not work anymore...